# Browser support by Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I know that Watir supports Firefox and Chrome.
Does someone know which versions of Firefox and Chrome are supported?

According to Watir web site they support Firefox 5 and that is a pretty old version.

Comment: Where on Watir web site have you found that it supports only Firefox 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Watir supports all recent versions of Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

At work, with the Webdriver backend, I had to downgrade from Firefox 13 to Firefox 10.0.2. That seems like a big difference, but they have been cranking out the FF versions lately. It's probably because of a change in port, but I am just speculating.